# Uploaded HTML template to WrodPress - CSS crash

Tags: css, wordpress

I've uploaded an HTML template to my WordPress website, but when I open it its CSS has a lot  of bugs, which are not appear on the HTML template before uploading it to the server.
I believe it happens because the new CSS of the template crashes with the  WordPress / Theme's CSS, that already on the server.
Is there an option to disconnect the CSS of the HTML template from WordPress / Theme, so outsource CSS will not affect it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS file in function.php in your theme